# Is there a way that I can manually control the thresholds between various range on choroplethr?

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

I would like to be able to manually control the thresholds between population ranges on `choroplethr` package.

```
library(choroplethr)

data(df_pop_county)        
data(continental_us_states)

county_choropleth(df_pop_county, 
                  state_zoom = continental_us_states)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cut` to create the custom breaks:

```
# rename the original "value" column if you don't want to write over it
names(df_pop_county) <- c("region", "original_value")

# define the breaks you want
df_pop_county$value <- cut(df_pop_county[["original_value"]],
                           breaks = c(0, 1e4, 5e4, 1e5, 5e5, 1e6, 1e7))
# if you want custom labels to go along with those breaks, then provide
# the labels argument in cut:
# cut(df_pop_county[["original_value"]],
#     breaks = c(0, 1e4, 5e4, 1e5, 5e5, 1e6, 1e7),
#     labels =c( "0-9999","10000-49999", "50000-99999", "100000-499999", "500000-999999", "1000000-10000000"))
```

[image]